# How to create an array of objects of a specific type, conforming to a protocol in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

My question is simple and hopefully just a matter of syntax. I'm trying to create an array of UIViewControllers which conform to my protocol. I am able to create this requirement as a function parameter:

```
func doSomething<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>(controller: T) { ... }
```

Now, I'd like to store those objects in an array, I was hoping I could have something like:

```
var viewControllers = Array<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>()
```

However, I can't figure out how to create this constraint on an array. Is this possible or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use a protocol that only your class conforms to and use this one to constrain your type:

```
protocol ClassProtocol {}
class Class : ClassProtocol {}

protocol Protocol {}

class SubClass : Class, Protocol {}


let x : protocol<ClassProtocol, Protocol> = SubClass()
```

The `Foundation` framework does this too with `NSObject` and `NSObjectProtocol`

Comment: While this works for restricting the type of objects in the array, I'm still left w/ the problem of needing to downcast the objects w/in my array whenever I need to reference properties specific to a UIViewController (since it is unknown that they are all subclasses of UIViewController). Right?

Comment: @KyleZaragoza You can declare the needed properties in the ClassProtocol. It's also done like this with NSObject and NSObjectProtocol